# Generate a CSV file from XML stream for MYSQL Import

Tags: php, mysql, xml, csv

I am trying to get data from a online XML file and save in CSV format. I was able to save the CSV file but the data is not saved properly as a comma separated CSV and due to which the data has no delimiter and is not getting imported in mysql properly. It imports in mysql in one column itself where there are 8 columns and it should be imported in different columns as per CSV data.

I am using

```
        $report = stream_get_contents($request->getReport());
            // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
            header('Content-type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');

            // do not cache the file
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
                $file = fopen('data.csv','w+');
                     fwrite($file,$report);
                     fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the lines without formatting them properly first. You should use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When i use this it gives me error an> Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given i